# Safety functions to prevent location faking

Tags: php, android, ios, location

I’d like to ask your opinion, what safety functions could I include in my mobile frontend - PHP backend project, to try to prevent location faking.

I read a lot of articles here and elsewhere too, but still I am curius masbe there are better ways.

The app sends every 10 seconds the user’s location to the server.

For example I came up with the idea, if between two locations 1000km was passed, (in 10 seconds), then the user might be a hacker so I ban him.

What could I do more than that, to try to prevent loc faking?

Answer (score 0):

shortly you cant - there are almost unlimited ways of fake your location.

i would collect a list of requirements ( accuracy, permitted modes of transport, are rooted devices allowed ?, ... ) and validate against these rules.

its almost the same problem that PokemonGo has, so maybe you will find there helpful informations about this. e.g. they introduce a 3-strike system, which means that if your sent location is detected as fake you get a strike. after 3 strikes your account/phone will be blocked ( or limit his rights related to features )

their old system was a white/black list of apps and processes on the running device
[How Niantic is detecting spoofers](https://www.reddit.com/r/PokemonGoSpoofing/comments/72v0a3/theory_how_niantic_is_detecting_spoofers/)